# How to bind HTML5 datalist to paper-input?

Tags: polymer

I need to bind a datalist to a paper-input element, something like we have here [HTML5 DataList Example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/html5-datalist-example/). It does not work as the example shows, can someone please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I don't believe a `paper-input` is what you are looking for.  If you look at the documentation at [The Polymer Project](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-input) it describes the `paper-input` as "paper-input is a single-line text field for user input".

What you might be looking for is the [`paper-dropdown-menu`](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-dropdown-menu) `(<-- look at ths link)` with a `core-menu` as the element you are going to bind your data to.

I included a skeleton of how you would bind your data.  Remember that you still need to add all the references to the Polymer elements, and polyfills.

```
<template is="auto-binding">    
  <!-- other content -->
  <paper-dropdown-menu>
    <paper-dropdown class="dropdown colored">
      <core-menu class="menu">
        <template repeat="{{countries}}">
          <paper-item>{{}}</paper-item>
        </template>
      </core-menu>
    </paper-dropdown>
  </paper-dropdown-menu>
</template>

<script>
  scope = document.querySelector('template[is=auto-binding]');
  scope.countries= [
      'Mexico',
      'United States',
      'Canada'
  ];
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and consideration, however, paper-dropdown will not provide the user experience I want. I want users to get suggestive text as they type in their country for example. That eliminates the need to scroll.

Comment: Understood. I found this component [lazy-autosuggest](http://component.kitchen/components/lazy-autosuggest) which might fit your needs.  It does not have the styling of a paper-input element, but I'm sure you can modify the css to your specifications.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended [by this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981869/paper-input-suggest-values-in-typeahead/27987754#27987754), you could wrap `paper-input-decorator` with `input` and `datalist` inside.
You would have the same result as with `paper-input` but more explicit and therefore more customizable.