# paper-input: Suggest values in typeahead

Tags: polymer, web-component, html-input

Is there an easy way to implement a typeahead using Polymer's `<paper-input>` element?
The [HTML `<datalist>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) seems to implement that for normal `<input>` tags and I could dynamically update the data list using templates.

However, this does nothing:

```
<paper-input
  label="Topic"
  list="dl">
</paper-input>
<datalist id="dl">
  <option>a</option>
  <option>aa</option>
  <option>aaa</option>
  <option>ab</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the fact you misuse options,

```
<datalist id="dl">
  <option value='a'></option>
  <!-- WRONG: <option>a</option> -->
</datalist>
```

I would suggest you to take a look into `paper-input` code and use `paper-input-decorator` with plain input as they do for `paper-input`:

```
<paper-input-decorator id="decorator">
  <input list="dl" is="core-input">
  <datalist id="dl">
    <option value='a'></option>
    <option value='ab'></option>
    <option value='ac'></option>
    <option value='ffa'></option>
  </datalist>
</paper-input-decorator>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Polymer/paper-input](https://github.com/Polymer/paper-input) has been deprecated, the currently supported version is [PolymerElements/paper-input](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input).

To use a datalist with paper-input in Polymer 1.0+:

```
<paper-input-container>
    <input list="choices" is="iron-input">
    <datalist id="choices">
        <option value='a'></option>
        <option value='ab'></option>
        <option value='ac'></option>
        <option value='ffa'></option>
    </datalist>
</paper-input-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin Combo Box https://vaadin.com/elements/-/element/vaadin-combo-box is a good apache-2 licensed option for a typeahead that fits in with the paper elements.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this element. It's an element has the typeahead function.

https://github.com/cheonhyangzhang/paper-typeahead-input

Here is the demo & doc page 
http://cheonhyangzhang.github.io/paper-typeahead-input/components/paper-typeahead-input/